# assign each thread a cpu core

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

i have a windows service written in .net 4 which doing jobs periodically using Threads.
the server has more than 20 cpu core.

i create 10 threads in my windows service. is it possible to assign each thread a cpu core?

Comment: Why would you want to second-guess the OS scheduler/dispatcher?  Such exercises rarely end well.

Comment: @Martin: curiosity and curiosity and curiosity

Comment: Sounds more like "i have no clue waht I do"

Comment: You should not care and controlo such behaviour.
I know you can indicate the max level of parallelism, hence the core usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OS already does precisely that for you. It doesn't guarantee that each thread will *stay* on the same core forever (and in nearly all cases, there's no need for that either), but it *does* try to keep as many cores busy as possible. Which means giving all available threads their own core as much as possible.

Comment: Very likely, but I'm not sure where to find it, just like I wouldn't be sure where to find documentation for the claim that the OS won't suddenly rewrite your process' memory space. It's operating systems 101. An OS which does *not* try to utilize all CPU cores is fundamentally broken.

Comment: to jalf: i read some documentations and i understand you are right!

Answer (score 6):

It is possible by tapping into the native Win32 system calls, specifically [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will need to do some DllImports:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetThreadAffinityMask(IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwThreadAffinityMask);
```

And then use them inside each spawned thread (with a different parameter for the mask, of course):

```
// set affinity of current thread to the given cpuID
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), new IntPtr(1 << (int)cpuID));
```

Warning: Direct correlation between .NET threads and OS threads is not guaranteed, at least according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can
>   use the Fiber API to schedule many managed threads against the same
>   operating system thread, or to move a managed thread among different
>   operating system threads.

Comment: -1. A .NET thread is a OS level thread. Down to rprogrammer being able to set stuff like therad isolation. This is pretty much gauranteed unless MS chagnes it - in a major .NET runtime upgrade.

Comment: @TomTom: I'm pretty sure what you are saying is not valid for all versions of .NET. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx. I also added the quote in my post.

Comment: And btw, I think I've answered his question, so I don't see the reason to downvote for a debatable sentence at the end.

Comment: Your link prooves my point  - a .NET thread is a OS level thread. And I nalways downvote answers that contain dangerous bad wrong information.

Comment: @TomTom: In the quote I posted it says that managed threads can be scheduled to the same kernel thread via fibers. How does that prove your point? I think it's the opposite. At this point you have not produced any conclusive source that confirms your point, except the fact that you don't agree with mine.

Comment: No, it says a runtime CAN decide to do that. Practically NONE does. Reality check. ALL threads ARE threads. Usage of Fiber API is discouraged. COM compatibility demands threads. Now, it says "because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads". NO host  that standard runs .NET programs does. Yes, it is POSSIBLE - if I host the runtime myself in my own unmanaged host. BUt that is a VERY special case that is VERY theoretical. NO host I know of deos so.

Comment: Not even normally (discouraged to turn on) sql server - and that is about the only server that exposes a "use fibers instead of threads" switch at all. DOcumentation says no to normally turn this on, btw. Your argumentation is exactly WHY i see a -1 to be warranted.

Comment: Even so, my comment at the end was meant as a precaution that it is possible in theory and I think it should be left there. The op is free to experiment with the code I posted and see for himself.

Comment: An operating-system ThreadId may have no fixed relationship to a managed thread UNLESS you make use of thread affinity  (signaled on by Thread.BeginThreadAffinity and off by Thread.EndThreadAffinity) within the entirety of your managed thread.

Comment: @TomTom Sorry bud, I have to disagree with you. Its not in the runtime necessarily. It can be from whatever CLR host your code is hosted on, like you said in a later post which contradicts your first post. I would play it safe just because I can, even in theoretical, special cases, especially if you're writing a library. Especially since you can't predict the future, but have the option to safeguard against it. Use thread affinity. That's why its there. -1 is not warranted. +1 to Tudor for a great answer.